# Web Applications not accepting questions about web applications

Tags: discussion, scope, meta

Trying to post for the second time a [question about HYPERLINKS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111305/hyperlinks-how-do-they-actually-work).
First on Stack Overflow, second on Web Applications (because error message said that it is a web-programming-related question). I should be correct here, but still seems off-topic.

May somebody bring some light into how to post a Q?

I provided problem, code, and example. If capitalization of some words like "hyperlink" is required it should be mentioned in the rules.

I cannot tag the question s off-topic - so I am including the reply to my question into this new question.

Also: How to reach out to people who vote or comment?

There seems no way to message them to ask how to do things correctly here.

> put on hold as off-topic by John C, serenesat, mhoran_psprep, pnuts, Rubén 22 hours ago
>
> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> It is a question about creating/developing a web application. – John C, serenesat, mhoran_psprep, Rubén
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

All of the information that you need can be found in the Help Center, which is linked from the close banner message.  At the link, you can find the following information:

> This question does not appear to be about web applications within the scope defined by the community. What's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, so it may be necessary to reword the question to fit this site's scope after reviewing the community guidelines.

Clicking on the link for "within the scope defined by the community" leads to:
Web Applications Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications.

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which 
>     behaves like an application
> - Bookmarklets
> - Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Your question is about web development (since it deals with hyperlink count limitations on a page).

---

As an aside, Stack Overflow *is* the right site for web programming questions, but I assume that, like me, users there really couldn't make heads or tails about what it was actually asking.